# Error - NSDictionary is not a subtype of "Class"

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, append

I have a "var" userMasterItemsList which stores an array of objects of other class (UserItemsList)

```
    var userMasterItemsList:[UserItemsList]?
```

And in some method, I want to add these objects of other class to the array after parsing them.

```
    var recievedItemsList = dict["itemsList"] as [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
    for itemsDict in recievedItemsList
    {
        var itemsModel = UserItemsList.initWithDictionary(itemsDict)
        userMasterItemsList?.append(itemsModel)
    }
```

My UserItemsList.initWithDictionary() receives a Dictionary. 
But it gives an error saying - 'NSDictionary' is not a subtype of 'UserItemsList'
Kindly guide. Thanks.

Comment: `recievedItemsList` is a dictionary but is treated as an array.

Comment: No, `recievedItemsList` is an array of dictionaries. `dict["itemsList"]` will give a list of items, with each item having its properties in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, how do you compose dict?